# Calculating concentration quotient and determining direction of reaction for equilibrium involving gases

Tags: physical-chemistry, thermodynamics, equilibrium, concentration

I'm currently working on a chemistry problem involving chemical equilibrium, and I'm having some trouble figuring out how to calculate the concentration quotient $Q$ and determine the direction in which the reaction will proceed.

At a certain temperature, when nitrogen dioxide $(\ce{NO2})$ is in equilibrium with nitrogen monoxide $(\ce{NO})$ and oxygen $(\ce{O2}),$ the equilibrium constant is $\pu{0.50 M}.$ A container with a volume of $\pu{0.50 dm3}$ initially contains $\pu{0.020 mol}$ of $\ce{NO2},$ $\pu{0.10 mol}$ of $\ce{NO},$ and $\pu{0.010 mol}$ of $\ce{O2}.$

Now, I need to calculate the concentration quotient $Q$ to determine whether the system is at equilibrium or not. If $Q$ is greater than the equilibrium constant, the reaction will proceed to the left, and if $Q$ is less than the equilibrium constant, the reaction will proceed to the right.

However, I'm not sure how to calculate $Q$ for this particular system. Could someone please walk me through the steps involved? Also, if you could let me know which direction the reaction is likely to proceed based on the value of $Q,$ that would be great.

Comment: You have merely just verbosely described the task in the hand. But you have not described what you have tried to do. Like learning what is the an equilibrium constant,  a reaction quotient, what is their relations and what the 0.50 M is hinting to you.